# Custom posts not paginating on archive page and returning 404

Tags: pagination, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying desperately to get the pagination on my custom post type archive page to work, but I keep getting a 404 error whenever I click on `<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>` for p2 of results.

Here's my situation:

- I've created a file called 'archive-bvdirectory.php' for my custom post type 'bvdirectory' (see how I've set it up in my functions.php below) and 'single-bvdirectory.php' for viewing single custom posts, both of which I can view fine.
- I *have deleted* a page called 'directory' I created permanently as I read this can cause problems with WP's rewrite rules (the URL would be the same, so that makes sense)
- I have refreshed my permalinks ad infinitum and it changes nothing.

Can anyone see a problem with my code or suggest something for me to try?

Thanks for your time,

Osu

**CTP and taxonomies are set up like this:**

```
function osu_bv_company() {

    // Create Directory custom post type
    register_post_type(
        'bvdirectory',
        array(
            'label'                 => __( 'Directory' ),
            'public'                => true,
            'has_archive'           => 'directory',
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'query_var'             => true,
            'supports'              => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'author',
                'excerpt',
                'post-thumbnails',
                'custom-fields',
                'revisions',
                'page-attributes',
                'thumbnail'
                // 'trackbacks',
                // 'comments'
            ),
            'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'directory')
        )
    );

    // Create Industry taxonomy
    $bvindustrylabels = array(
        'name'                      => 'Industry',
        'singular_name'             => 'Industry',
        'search_items'              => 'Search industries',
        'all_items'                 => 'All industries',
        'parent_item'               => 'Parent industry',
        'edit_item'                 => 'Edit industry',
        'update_item'               => 'Update industry',
        'add_new_item'              => 'Add new industry',
        'new_item_name'             => 'New industry name',
        'choose_from_most_used'     => 'Choose from most used industries'
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'bvindustry',
        'bvdirectory',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $bvindustrylabels,
            'sort' => true,
            'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'industry')
        )
    );
    // Create Company Size taxonomy
    $bvcosizelabels = array(
        'name'                      => 'Company size',
        'singular_name'             => 'Company size',
        'search_items'              => 'Search company sizes',
        'all_items'                 => 'All company sizes',
        'parent_item'               => 'Parent company size',
        'edit_item'                 => 'Edit company size',
        'update_item'               => 'Update company size',
        'add_new_item'              => 'Add new company size',
        'new_item_name'             => 'New company name',
        'choose_from_most_used'     => 'Choose from most used company sizes'
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'bvsize',
        'bvdirectory',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $bvcosizelabels,
            'sort' => true,
            'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'size')
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'osu_bv_company');
```

**I have the following arguments set for my loop in archive-bvdirectory.php**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    // General args
    'post_type'             =>  'bvdirectory',
    'posts_per_page'        =>  2,
    'orderby'               =>  'title', // set this in form
    'order'                 =>  'ASC', // Set this in form
    'paged'                 =>  $paged  
);

// Filter posts
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: Ok, some additional details - I re-added the 'directory' page and am using a template for that instead of 'archive-bvdirectory.php' for controlling the look of the Custom Posts as the slug for my custom posts is 'bvdirectory', so I think there must be no conflict there. Using this new 'directory' page, I can get pagination to work ONLY when I select the same number of `posts_per_page` in the admin end i.e. I select 2 for 'Blog pages show at most'. I guess this is a workaround for the moment, but I think I need to find a proper solution rather than this...

Answer (score 2):

Your error is likely `get_query_var('paged')` should be `get_query_var('page')`.

*However...*

You should avoid calling `query_posts` in the template, it is a waste of resources, as you're just discarding the original query which has already happened.

Hook [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to instead alter the query before it happens:

```
function wpa60728_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( 'bvdirectory' == get_post_type() && is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa60728_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Hi Milo - how do I set the parameters in my loop then if I don't use `query_posts`? i.e. setting the limit of posts to show, ordering etc? My ultimate aim with this is to allow users to filter posts on this page by submitting a form with with my custom taxonomies. Oh, and I changed the 'paged' to 'page', but it doesn't seem to have sorted it... thanks for your help so far